# AFNetworkReachabilityManager only emits RACSignal once

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, reactive-cocoa

I'm just starting to use ReactiveCocoa in my project, and came up with this problem: I tried using RACObserve to get the network reachability status change so that I can set the button status. In my ViewController, I use below code:

```
AppDelegate *AppDele = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
RACSignal *reachableNetworkSignal = [AppDele.reachableNetworkSignal doNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"%@",x);
}];
```

and in my AppDelegate:

```
- (RACSignal *)reachableNetworkSignal {
return RACObserve([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager], reachable);
```

}

I suppose when network status changed, I should be able to see the change in console. However I only got it once when the VC was inited. Why?
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the signal?

Comment: I'm not explicitly subscribing to it, but using it as an RACCommand initWithEnable argument like this:
`[[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:reachableNetworkSignal
                        signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {}];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIButton *aBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
aBtn.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:[self network] signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    NSLog(@"has network");
    return [RACSignal empty];
}];

- (RACSignal *)network {
return RACObserve([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager], reachable);
}
```

this works for me.

Comment: Turned out there's sth wrong with my AFNetworking code. The RAC solution is similar to this. Thanks...